# Azure Devops CI: task: sftpupload@1 access issue, Need Australia East Azure DevOps IP

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Azure DevOps CI: task: sftpupload@1 access issue

I need to copy my Artifacts to to private server through ftps. The server only allow IP's it know to access the server. How can I find Australia East Azure DevOps IP that I need to white list. Can any one help ?

Comment: So... you don't have any access issue, you're just asking what the ip ranges are? If that's the case, you should really re-write the title & question.

Comment: I'm looking in to possibility to use web API exposed from my server to Azure devops to upload the artifact to my server

Answer (score 0):

> How can I find Australia East Azure DevOps IP that I need to white list. Can any one help ?

It seems you are use Microsoft-hosted agent to run your task: `sftpupload@1`. For the Microsoft-hosted agent white list, you could check the document [Microsoft-hosted agents Agent IP ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops#agent-ip-ranges) for some more details:

> Azure DevOps uses the Azure global network, IP ranges vary over time.
>   We publish a [weekly JSON file](https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=56519) listing IP ranges for Azure datacenters,
>   broken out by region. **This file is published every Wednesday (US
>   Pacific time) with new planned IP ranges. The new IP ranges become
>   effective the following Monday**. We recommend that you check back
>   frequently to ensure you keep an up-to-date list. If agent jobs begin
>   to fail, a key first troubleshooting step is to make sure your
>   configuration matches the latest list of IP addresses.

So, you could check that json file for the Microsoft-hosted agent white list.

Besides, if you want the white list for the Azure DevOps IP instead of Microsoft-hosted agent, you could check the document [Allowed address lists and network connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/allow-list-ip-url?view=azure-devops#private-build-agents) for some more details.

Hope this helps.